# jQuery find next table

Tags: jquery

I have page that has a search form and a table where the results load. I am trying to use jQuery to locate the next instance of a table but for some reason I can't find it.

```
<div class="search">
  <form class="search" method="get" action="/page.php">
    <input id="search" type="text" value="" name="search">
    <input type="submit" value="search">
  </form>
</div>

<table id="Organization" class="table" width="100%" >
...table stuff...
</table>
```

Using jQuery I am trying to "onclick" of the search button I'm trying to grab the next instance of a table and get the class of that table. I have tried this and it does not work:

```
$(this).next('table').attr('class');
```

Can someone please help me select the next instance of a table after clicking the search button on my form?

Answer (score 3):

The [jQuery Documentation for `next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) says:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .next() method allows us to search through the immediately following **sibling** of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

That means that with next you only can find elements that follow the selected element immediately on the same level. According to that the following should work:

```
$(".search").next("table").attr('class');
```

If you have multiple elements with the class `search` you can use the `$.parents` method to find the `search` div in the ancestors and then look for the next table.

```
$(this).parents(".search").next("table").attr('class');
```

But why do you use `next()` at all? You can select the table e.g. by its class or by an id if you assign it one.

The modified table (extended by attribute `id`) would be:

```
<table id="the_table" class="table">...</table>
```

Methods to select the table:

```
$(".table").attr('class'); // by class
$("#the_table").attr('class'); // by id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('div').next('table');
```

Comment: Explain what you're doing and format your code, please.